# How are JSON and TEXT types in MySQL(InnoDB) stored and how it affects read performance

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance

I would like to know in depth around how exactly JSON and TEXT are stored in MySQL InnoDB. I have heard and read in some places that for these types only a pointer is stored in the row with the actual data residing elsewhere on disk.

- Would the length of these types(especially in JSON) affect the decision of whether they are being stored at a different location with a pointer in the row(in the case where JSON size is large) or at the same location as the row without any pointer (in the case where JSON size is small)?
- If a pointer is always stored, then wouldn't keeping the datatype as JSON for any JSON doc someone would have to store(as it would seem the right type choice to store a JSON due to the datatype name, even though the size of JSON is small) would affect badly read performance as now every row has to fetch its JSON document from a separate location for each row.
- Provided

  - I always insert a valid JSON in MySQL
  - I am only reading the full document and not querying the JSON
  - My size of JSON is predictable and small < 1000 chars let's say

Would VARCHAR be a better choice as compared to JSON datatype from a read performance perspective as now data would reside along with row and not in separate locations hence saving the additional disk pages fetch?

- Is there any metric around how much would read performance get affected by having a JSON vs VARCHAR?
- In case a JSON column is to be used, would it be a better choice to keep all JSON in a single column rather than creating multiple JSON columns in order to avoid multiple pointer-based fetches?
- Is the effect on read performance due to additional disk read due to pointer-based fetch of JSON negligible that I should not think about this kind of optimization (considering I am dealing with designs of tables that could have millions to billions of rows)?

Comment: If you are using JSON .. why are you using MySQL and NOT using MongoDB which was designed specifically to house JSON based data, versus having columns and rows like a conventional database.  Is it possible to FORCE it to work?  Probably, but you are going to have so many character validations per input that Godhelp you if you forget a single special character that doesn't translate between languages. EDIT - says you are validating so thats good at least.

Comment: If you are doing 1000 characters you might need to do BLOB type instead of VarCHAR at least for efficiency, especially since you are just dumping the data and don't plan on having to query it.

Comment: First, I have to ask what version are you using. You can check with `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: JSON is encoded in a binary format, to make it more efficient to access named properties and array indexes. I haven't been able to find detailed documentation of this format.

Comment: @easleyfixed My whole data is not json dump, only a small part of it is, Its a very common practice for me to store certain properties like data as json string rather than keeping a lot of columns which wouldn't make sense other, most of data is in separate columns, more over in a lot of my designing of schema i highly use clustered index and its advantages hence mysql

Comment: @BillKarwin my current cluster is 5.7.12 but i don't mind if the answers are given for version 8 as well as we are soon going to migrate to version 8. I am aware in 8 there have been some optimisations around partial update of JSON which was not there in  5.7 but my use cases generally don't involve partial reading or updating of the columns which are kept as json.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware of that hence I mentioned in question that my use cases don't involve partial selects of json columns.

Comment: It may still be useful to use the JSON datatype, since numbers in the JSON can be stored more compactly in binary, rather than as text. But this could be cancelled by the overhead of the indexing information for the property names, as well as the conversion overhead.

Comment: @easleyfixed there are lots of benefits to use JSON for some parts of your database, and relational data for everything else. Keeping everything in 1 database has a ton of advantages.

Comment: If you are looking for searching for a few rows with a certain value, we need to discuss the details of the indexing.  And whether your version has sparse indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, JSON is a subtype of BLOB. Cf. https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/field.h#L143-L150

(I had to ask the version because some people tag their question mysql when they are really using MariaDB. MariaDB has a different implementation for JSON than MySQL, and I have no idea how MariaDB stores it.)

You should use the JSON type if you store valid JSON (if you store fragments of JSON, you can't use the JSON type).

BLOB, TEXT, VARCHAR, VARBINARY, and thus also JSON are stored the same in InnoDB. There will be no advantage to choosing VARCHAR over JSON.

The default InnoDB row format in both MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 is DYNAMIC, so I'll comment assuming you use the default row format. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-dynamic for a description.

If a given string (BLOB/TEXT/VARCHAR/VARBINARY/JSON) is short enough to fit within 40 bytes, this row format stores it inline on the same page with other columns. Otherwise it stores the string on one or more additional pages, and on the primary page, it stores a 20-byte pointer to the first additional page. Thus it *might* multiple page reads to fetch one of these data types, but it depends on the length.

Each page is of fixed size (16KB by default). If the string is too long to fit on one additional page, it is split over multiple pages, and the pages aren't necessarily consecutive. Each page points to the next page for the continuation of the string.

I don't have an answer about the metrics you were interested in. Storage doesn't have performance; that's relative to specific queries you will run. As described above, it also depends on the length of your JSON documents. It could also depend on your server power, amount of RAM available for caching pages, and other concurrent queries competing for RAM. The only way you'll get an accurate answer for that question is to run some tests yourself, using your own data on your own server.

I also can't answer about whether it's better for your case to separate the data into multiple JSON documents versus combine them all into one. One reason is that your query patterns may naturally need to use a small subset of the JSON data more frequently, so it would be an advantage to store that separately. But if you always need to read the whole JSON content, then there's no reason not to combine them into one. No one on Stack Overflow can answer this for you, because it depends on your query needs.

Comment: As I read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-compression-internals.html , a text/blob of more than 40 bytes _may sometimes_ be stored on-page.  This happens when the row fits in about 8KB or it is bigger, but some other column are moved off-page.

Comment: @RickJames I haven't been able to find a clear enough description to confirm how that works.

Comment: @BillKarwin https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-dynamic , in DYNAMIC row format it specially mentions that TEXT and BLOB greater than 40 bytes are stored off page, so isn't the storage behaviour actually different compared to VARCHAR ? would VARCHAR uptill 768 bytes still be stored on same page ? is 40 byte condition applied on TEXT only when row size is large or always ?

Comment: @Luv - That page says "When a row is too long, the longest columns are chosen for off-page storage" -- I take that to mean that _some+ columns will _sometimes_ be put off-page.  Elsewhere, I think I read that `VARCHAR` (and `VARBLOB`) are treated like `TEXT` (and `BLOB`).  This would make sense -- simply handle big columns in a "too large" row with a single mechanism.

Comment: Yes, VARCHAR is treated the same as TEXT and BLOB in this way in InnoDB.